# Java ArrayList into HashMap doesn't print the correct entries

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a phonebook program with one main and one PhoneBook class as follows

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JavaApplication9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        PhoneBook p = new PhoneBook();
        String name;
        String name2;
        String number;
        int sw;

        do
        {           
            System.out.println("Choose");
            System.out.println("1. Input new contact and number info");
            System.out.println("2. Search"); 
            System.out.println("3. Show contacts and numbers");
            System.out.println("4. exit");

                sw = inp.nextInt();

                switch (sw)
                {
                    case 1: System.out.println("Input name");
                            name = inp.nextLine();
                            inp.nextLine(); //to bypass the nextLine-skip 

                            System.out.println("Input number");
                            number = inp.nextLine();

                            p.addNumber(name, number);
                            break;

                    case 2: System.out.println("Input name to search");
                            name2 = inp.nextLine();

                            p.showNumbersOf(name2);
                            break;

                    case 3: p.show();
                            break;

                    case 4: 
                }
            } while(sw!=4);
        }
```

PhoneBook class

```
        public class PhoneBook {

        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> catalog = new HashMap<>();
        String name;
        String number;



            public void addNumber(String aName, String aNumber)
            {
                name = aName;

                if (catalog.get(name) == null) 
                {
                    catalog.put(name, new ArrayList());
                }

                catalog.get(name).add(aNumber);
                catalog.put(name, catalog.get(name));     
            }

            public void showNumbersOf(String aName)
            {
                name = aName;


                if (catalog.containsKey(name))
                {

                    for (String it1 : catalog.keySet())
                    {
                        if (aName.equals(it1))
                        {
                            System.out.println(catalog.get(it1));
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("No such contact");
                }
            }


            public void show()
            {
                for (String name: catalog.keySet())
                System.out.println(name + catalog.get(name));  
            }    

        }
```

So when I add a contact like 
Nick
5550100
and decide to show,
it should print Nick[55501000]
but it prints [55501000] (with a space where the name should be)

also when using showNumberOf it seems to skip the entire

```
        name2 = inp.nextLine;
```

unless I comment out the previous inp.nextLine commands from case 1 and even then it has the exact same problem with show().

I can't get figure what I'm doing wrong when putting the entries in the HashMap and/or when recovering them so please help me.

Comment: Tell me: what does `//to bypass the nextLine-skip ` mean and why have you put it in the place where it is?

Comment: `name = inp.nextLine();` <- `nextLine()` returns a blank string so you set the name to blank. `inp.nextLine(); //to bypass the nextLine-skip ` <- `nextLine()` returns the name and you ignore it.

Comment: As I've come to understand, when you put consecutive nextLine commands, the second one takes the "enter" you pressed when inputting the first line and effectively doesn't let you input a second line.
so the random nextLine is there to 'consume' the enter from the buffer.

I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: "As I've come to understand, when you put consecutive nextLine commands, the second one takes the "enter" you pressed when inputting the first line and effectively doesn't let you input a second line." - no, that is completely untrue.

Comment: I tried deleting the nextLine with the comment and now it just skips the first nextLine entirely printing out the two System.out.println at the same time and only after letting me input anything, and I can only input one string.  
  
edit: Have a look at the link I provided in the previous comment, it's the same situation.

Comment: If *you* look at the link you provided in the previous comment, you'll see that the *first* `nextLine` call after a call to `nextInt` gets "skipped".